# Sobel Gradient Angle Resolution

Tags: image-processing, sobel

When applying a Sobel operator to an image in X and Y direction and computing an angle (`atan2`) from the resulting X/Y vector, I seem to get gradient directions in 45 degree steps. Does a Sobel only produce 8 directions in 45 degree steps or should I get exact angles or could it be a rounding error?

I use the sobel convolution for `Gx` and `Gy` mentioned here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

Comment: A Sobel operator will get a gradient direction in just 1 angle, not several. Can you show a MCVE?

Comment: Sorry, didn't describe it sufficiently. I'm computing the sobel for X and Y. Updated question.

Comment: You still don't show any code that can reproduce your claims. Sobel, if computed on a floating poing image, shouldn't give you such 45deg discretization. I'm guessing you are having integer rounding errors, but hard to say without seeing any code.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo well technically yes it does, it will enhance *mostly* those 8 directions. I am writting an answer

Comment: If you are just using `Gx` and `Gy` and not the diagonal Sobel operators, and you are doing `atan2(Gx/Gy)` as Imanol suggest, then you may be having float/int problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes using the classing Sobel operators. Lets try to understand what you are doing here:

A Sobel operator to detect vertical lines looks like:

```
[-1 0 1
 -2 0 2
 -1 0 1]
```

If you apply this to a pixel (put this on top of the pixel, and use the values in neighbor pixels, then add up everything), it will only have a non-zero value if pixels in the right have different values as pixels in the left. If that is the case it meas there is a vertical edge.

Following, the 45 degree Sobel operator:

```
[-2 -1  0
 -1  0  1
 0   1  2]
```

If you understood how the vertical one works, this should be easy to understand.  the biggest values will happen when the diagonal of this matrix has different values, thus a 45 degrees edge.

**Before continuing**, lets note a thing, mentioned by @ImanolLuengo in the comments: The 45 degree Sobel operator will actually see a 30 degree slope, it will just give it a smaller value. It will enhance it less. You can test this by yourself if you want to.

Now, with a 3x3 matrix, you can see that its going to be quite hard to get a 30 degree edge, basically because the fact that the kernel we use is discreet and small (3x3) doesn't allow us to create a kenrel that enhances other angles.

However, using the same logic as in the Sobel operator, we can think of a bigger sized kernel that can enhance any arbitrary angle.

For example the following kernel will enhance 30 degrees mostly:

```
[1  1  1  1  0 
 1  1  0  0  0 
 0  0  0 -1 -1 
 0 -1 -1 -1 -1]
```

It is a "by hand approximation of the kenrel, because as you note in Sobel, some  kernel elements have bigger numbers than others. The rule for this numbers is: Higher value in the direction of the edge you want to detect, and higher value in the ones that actually go trough the center of the kernel.

This will not be a Sobel operator, but you can just make up any kernels that will do the job you want.

Comment: I think the op meant to compute `atan2(Gy, Gx)`, being `Gx` and `Gy` sobel horizontal and vertical filters respecrively.

Comment: It is what I did understand from *computing an angle from the resulting X/Y vector* at least haha.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo could be, he added the Gx Gy info later >.<. AS tehre are Sobel operators for 8 directions *by default* I asnwered assuming he uses those